# PostgreSQL ERROR: could not write to hash-join temporary file: Out of memory

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I have a PostgreSQL 9.6.10 with a database of about 380 Gb of storage.

In the database live several tables with relations to each other.

I would like to start cleaning things up. Old records will be deleted.

I wrote a script like this:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (...subquery...);
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id IN (...subquery...);
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE id IN (...subquery...);
DELETE FROM table4 WHERE id IN (...subquery...);
DELETE FROM table5 WHERE id IN (...subquery...);
DELETE FROM table6 WHERE id IN (...subquery...);
DELETE FROM table7 WHERE id IN (...subquery...);
END;
```

So, multiple tables will be cleaned, AND multiple records per table.

However, after a while I get this error:

```
DELETE 3026083
psql:/script.sql:227: ERROR:  could not write to hash-join temporary file: Out of memory
psql:/script.sql:336: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/script.sql:445: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/script.sql:554: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/script.sql:662: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/script.sql:770: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK
```

And, indeed, my server is totally out of memory, including swap memory.

I tried minimizing the amount that can be deleted in order to reduce the needed memory. But still the transaction gets too big.

Can you explain why (when deleting!) so much information gets into memory? And how I can prevent this from happening?

**edit**

One query that takes a very long time shows this query plan:

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=3730488.45..3730488.46 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1267800.53..3725856.25 rows=1852879 width=0)
         Hash Cond: (table1.table2_id = table2.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..1835507.87 rows=57356787 width=8)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1254056.17..1254056.17 rows=837709 width=8)
               ->  Gather  (cost=1002.84..1254056.17 rows=837709 width=8)
                     Workers Planned: 1
                     ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=2.84..1169285.27 rows=492770 width=8)
                           Hash Cond: (table2.table3_id = table3.id)
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..1058067.65 rows=36375365 width=16)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=2.70..2.70 rows=11 width=8)
                                 ->  Index Scan using idx_table3_some_id on table3  (cost=0.28..2.70 rows=11 width=8)
                                       Index Cond: (some_id = 44265)
```

(i rewrote the table names; they have no relation with the DELETE statements above; however most of them are in there).

Now, I realize the approach I took. I decided to delete the leaves first and then work my way up. Is it maybe smarter to take another approach?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete rows on tables with foreign key constraints, it enqueues system triggers to verify that foreign key constraints are maintained.  This takes memory.  That is the most likely cause of the out of memory condition, though there are other possibilities.  How many rows are you trying to delete?

9.6.10 is quite old, both in turns of bug-fix releases (9.6.19) and feature releases (current is 12.4).  I wouldn't put too much work into investigating this until running at least the latest bugfix release.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes I have foreign keys indeed. I added a query plan in my original question;  this also shows the amounts of records for 1 deletion (of many).